# xcopy cyclic copy .txt files

Tags: batch-file, text, xcopy

I am trying to use XCopy to copy all text files of folder structure to another folder, while copying the subfolder structure.

Here is what I have

```
xcopy /s "./Folder1/*.txt" "./Folder2/
```

The error I am getting is `" Cannot perform a cyclic copy"`

Any help?

Comment: Have tou tried supplying absolute paths?

Comment: Not an option seeing that I'm using it in drop box.

Comment: I mean just for testing... the error you get appear usually when recursive source and target locations overlap... by the way, there is a closing `"` missing...

Answer (score 3):

It works with backslashes:

```
xcopy /s ".\Folder1\*.txt" ".\Folder2\"
```

Comment: That's my answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38858718/npm-script-copy-package-json-to-dist-when-bundling/51371023#51371023

Answer (score 0):

Did you check if you are copying something where it hits the file which is running? I've experienced that if the command I'm running is somewhere where the command actually hits it stops with that error