# npm script, copy package.json to dist when bundling

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to add a second part to my npm bundle script. The first part runs great, however I am trying to copy in 3 files along with the bundle.

So right now I have :

```
"bundle": "NODE_ENV=production webpack --output-file bundledFile.js && cp package.json dist/",
```

The `NODE_ENV=production webpack --output-file bundledFile.js` works great by itself. The part that is not working is the `&& cp package.json dist/`, I would like the script to copy my package.json (along with 2 other files actually, but just starting with this one) to the dist folder. Brand new to these scripts, any idea how to fix? Appreciate any advice, thanks!

Comment: Careful with using `cp` from the command line, as that won't typically be compatible for windows users (might not be a concern for you, though). Other than that, this looks right to me. You should be able to chain package.json scripts with `&&`. Are you getting any specific error? What happens if you make the two items two separate tasks, and then chain them instead? (`npm run build:bundle && npm run build:package-json` or something similar).

Comment: @dvlsg thanks for the response, would you recommend something other than cp? also can I use the same syntax for multiple single files ( i want to add the readme and npmrc for example)

Comment: If you're copying multiple files, and webpack doesn't support what you need (not sure about that), I would consider adding a build utility file. You don't need to go all the way to `gulp` or anything (although I do love `gulp`) -- you could just create a node file called `copy-files.js` and have it use the `fs` package to copy files. That would be (mostly) cross-platform since it's using node to handle copying files. Then you could call it with just `node copy-files.js` in your npm scripts. You'd still have to assume that `node` is available, but that's not too far of a stretch.

Comment: @dvlsg that's perfect if you want to add that as an answer, that is exactly what I am looking for.

Comment: I can add it as an answer, but maybe first check to see if splitting up the commands into two tasks `npm run build:bundle`, `npm run build:package-json`) and then setting `build: npm run build:bundle && npm run build:package-json` works for you. I still think we're going to have a problem with chaining commands, for whatever reason.

Comment: @dvlsg  I added `&& npm run copy` , and the copy script looks like, `"cp package.json dist/ && cp README.md dist/ && cp .npmrc dist/"` , this seems to work great.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

The syntax should work (and seems to, looking at your comments). I would suggest splitting your npm scripts across multiple points, though:

```
{
  "bundle": "NODE_ENV=production webpack --output-file bundledFile.js",
  "copy": "cp package.json dist/ && cp README.md dist/ && cp .npmrc dist/",
  "build": "npm run bundle && npm run copy"
}
```

In order to be cross-platform compatible (`cp` is not typically available on windows), I would also suggest adding a build file somewhere such as `./tools/copy-distrubution-files.js` which would make use of `fs` to [copy the necessary files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11293857/fastest-way-to-copy-file-in-node-js), then call it in the npm scripts with `node ./tools/copy-distribution-files.js`. That will be (mostly) platform independent (you still have to assume that `node` is available as the nodejs executable, but that seems fairly reasonable to me).

Comment: @mardok That depends whether or not you have the utility. I have Linux tools on my windows and `cp` works.

Comment: Use [ncp](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ncp) instead of `cp` if you'd like to support cross-OS environments

Comment: CP works on Windows with Git Bash, just make sure you run your commands through there :)

Answer (score 8):

The quickest way for me was to reference powershell in a package.json script like this:

```
"copyFile": "@powershell copy './source/package.json' './deploy'",
```

Comment: You saved me from suiciding

Answer (score 6):

If you're running on windows use the following command:

```
"copy": "copy \"package.json\" \"dist\" && copy \"README.md\" \"dist\" && copy \".npmrc\" \"dist\""
```

copy instead of cp.
Don't forget to use ***""*** for each path (escape them with ***\*** within the quoted command). and if you need to define a long path, don't use / (slashes) but \ (backslashes)

like:

```
copy "devices\\VS-88UT\\index.html" "devices\\VS-88UT\\dist"
```

Also, if you prefere ther is a [nice plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack-shell-plugin) to run bash command before and after each build

Comment: This isn't valid JSON.  Can you please clean up the quotes so I can easily paste this into my package.json

Answer (score 4):

## Use Node

Using Node.js built-in functionality, instead of depending on shell commands that aren't available on every OS, is the way to go. All other answers on this page should be avoided for that reason.

With current Node.js versions, one can use [`fs.copy`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69807672/3492994) to copy files and folders. Combining it with `node -e "javascript code goes here"`, one can write short, cross-platform npm scripts.

```json
"copyAssets": "node -e \"require('fs').cpSync('./assets', './build/assets', {recursive: true});\""
```

will copy the `/assets` folder to the `/build/assets` folder.

Answer (score 0):

To copy folders and files in windows just use

```
xcopy git\\* dist\\ /e /i /h
```

I think this might help someone.